# verselinenumbersleft with twocolumn

Tags: two-column, line-numbering, verse, poetry

Situation: a poem in the `verse` environment of the [`verse`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/verse/verse.pdf) package, while the entire page is set with the `twocolumn` option. Line numbering is enabled via `\poemlines{1}` and set to the left by `\verselinenumbersleft`.

Problem: The line numbers of the right column appear on the very left, while those of the left column don't show up at all (They might be covered by the right column's numbers?).

How do I get the line numbers of the right column to appear in between the two columns? (Hoping this would result in the reappearance of the left column numbers)

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{verse}
\begin{document}
\begin{verse}
\poemlines{1}
\verselinenumbersleft
aaa\\aaa\\aaa\\\newpage{}aaa\\aaa\\aaa\\
\end{verse}
\end{document}
```

Edit: `\poemlines{1}` means every line is to be numbered, the `\newpage{}` serves simply to make the WE a MWE ... the problem is the same without it and with many more verses/lines instead.

[image: Output]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For some reason, the line numbers are getting pushed *waaaay* over to the left in `twocolumn`. Anyway, this sort of works:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{verse}
\begin{document}
\begin{verse}
\poemlines{1}
\setlength{\vrightskip}{-9cm}
\verselinenumbersleft
aaa\\aaa\\aaa\\\newpage{}
aaa\\aaa\\aaa\\
\end{verse}
\end{document}
```

`\vrightskip` tells the environment how far over to typeset the line numbers. All I've done is nudge it back onto the page. Some tweaking may be required depending on how far over you want the numbers and so on. `-10cm` moves the numbers more right, `-8cm` moves it more to the left.